# Distributed Tensorflow model is no faster than standalone

Tags: python, tensorflow, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I need some help debugging Tensorflow, as moving from a single GPU model to multi-machine, multi-gpu cluster doesn't improve performance.
I thought it would be best to use the template from Tensorflow's Github issue page, so have included it below.

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**:
  I have taken the [Resnet code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/resnet) from the Tensorflow model zoo and distributed it as according to https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**:
  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**:
  Official Tensorflow-GPU docker image
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**:
  ('v1.0.0-2378-g2259213', '1.1.0-rc0')
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**:
  N/A
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**:
  Version 8
- **GPU model and memory**:
  Tested on multiple setups within a cluster
  4 machines with 2x Nvidia TitanX 12GB
  1 machine with 2x GeForce GTX 1080 8GB
- **Exact command to reproduce**:
  The commands differ slightly between machines depending on cluster configuration, but for 1 PS and 2 workers it looks like this:

`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" python resnet_main.py --dataset="cifar10" --train_data_path="/notebooks/cifar_data/data_batch*" --train_dir="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model/train" --log_root="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model" --job_name="ps" --task_index=0 --eval_data_path="/notebooks/cifar_data/test_batch.bin" --eval_dir="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model/test"`

`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python resnet_main.py --dataset="cifar10" --train_data_path="/notebooks/cifar_data/data_batch*" --train_dir="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model/train" --log_root="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model" --job_name="worker" --task_index=0 --eval_data_path="/notebooks/cifar_data/test_batch.bin" --eval_dir="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model/test"`

`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python resnet_main.py --dataset="cifar10" --train_data_path="/notebooks/cifar_data/data_batch*" --train_dir="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model/train" --log_root="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model" --job_name="worker" --task_index=1 --eval_data_path="/notebooks/cifar_data/test_batch.bin" --eval_dir="/notebooks/tmp/resnet_model/test"`

#### Describe the problem

When running the Resnet model on CIFAR10 from the tf zoo in a distributed environment (asynchronous, between-graph replication), there is no performance gain.

Running Resnet 110 on a single (non-distributed) machine, single GPU resulted in approximately 3 iterations per second. This is considered the baseline for any tests on the following configurations - all of which resulted in approximately the same number of iterations per second irrespective of configuration.
*Note: in all cases, each worker has their own dedicated GPU*
1. 1 PS, 2 workers on one machine
2. 1 PS with dedicated GPU & 1 worker on one machine, 1 worker on another machine
3. 1 PS & 2 workers on one machine, 2 workers on another machine
4. 1 PS & 2 workers on one machine, 3 more machines with 2 workers each
5. 4 machines with 2 workers each, two of these with 1 PS each
6. 4 machines, each with 1 PS & 2 workers

When starting up the workers, each would begin training as soon as it's ready, printing information to the terminal during/after each iteration. The difference is speed is visually noticeable - when there is only 1 worker running, it's as fast as I would expect. As more workers spin up, all of the existing workers slow down. In this way, I can see (with 8 terminals on my screen) the entire cluster slowing as more workers begin.

I monitored system stats during training to rule things out as the bottleneck and found the following for each machine:
- CPU usage: CPU usage is not at 100% for any machine
- GPU usage: GPU usage repeatedly flickers between 0% and ~80% - once per iteration
- Network usage: Network bandwidth in/out for any given machine is never more than ~80% of its capacity. the network speed is limited to 1Gbps, and it doesn't reach this cap. We raised the limit to 2Gbps and saw no increased usage or performance.
- HDD usage: Batches are loaded from disk multi-threaded. I printed to the screen during file-access and it's practically instantaneous.

For the input pipeline, I have also tried switching between `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` and `tf.train.shuffle_batch` and playing with the number of threads/min after deque etc for each of these batching methods to no avail.

#### Source code / logs

Source code files attached below - `cifar_input.py` has small modifications from the original input pipeline. The original cifar input code is the file `cifar_input_orig.py`

[resnet_distrib.zip](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/files/950254/resnet_distrib.zip)

**Thank you in advance for any light you may be able to shed on this!**

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow when appropriately configured has near perfect scaling up to 8 GPUs within a single machine, and across a cluster of machines each with multiple GPUs. For context, see our Benchmarks page: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/benchmarks

A couple common pitfalls:

1. It's important to compile TensorFlow with optimizations enabled. The open source pre-compiled versions of TensorFlow are compiled with optimizations disabled in order to ensure they can run on the largest possible number of machines.
2. It's important to use the latest versions of TensorFlow. There have been significant performance improvements in TensorFlow 1.0, 1.1, and the soon-to-be-released TensorFlow 1.2.
3. It's important to run an optimized input pipeline. Depending on the model, it's possible the Python code to drive TensorFlow is a significant overhead.

If you would like reproducible performance benchmarks, check out the https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks repository.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot generate the save results on the benchmark website. I ran tensorflow from docker which is nightly build